Is bacterial "colonization" restricted to human body surfaces not the deep tissues?
This seems to be the point where the perspective of human beings from a medical viewpoint intersects with that from an ecological perspective.

Colonization is the presence of bacteria on a body surface (like on
the skin, mouth, intestines or airway) without causing disease in the
person. Gale Encyclopedia of Medicine


These bacteria [Enterococcus, Proteus, Pseudomonas, Micrococcus,
Klebsiella, Enterobacter, Serratia, Acinetobacter, and Citrobacter]
colonize deep tissues and may cause an immediate inflammatory reaction
but also may remain dormant in deep tissues. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4487244/

I'm confused now whether dormant microorganisms in deep tissues are "invading" the human being or merely "colonizing" it.
Is the process of reaching deep tissues almost always result in a disease?

The presence of indwelling medical devices (catheters, stents, etc.) should be considered when evaluating positive cultures from normally
sterile sites such as the blood, cerebral spinal fluid, pleura, etc.
If no such devices exist, then the isolate represents an infection and
should be treated.
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40121-022-00597-w

Maybe the mean (or the process) itself, not the end, what matters, in other words, bacteria getting into the blood vs. bacteria in the blood, but how and why? Maybe invasive factors, the factors how the organism reached the blood, are usually sufficiently immunogenic?

I think you should go and look up the terms invasion and colonization in a dictionary. Invasion just means entry into, colonization means setting up residence.

how do bacterial infections kill people?

Awfully big question you've put in the comments. Can you narrow it down and show your research, then post it as a separate question in its own thread.
